# How do I make input text from textboxes store in databse whilst preventing security flaws

Tags: python, html, database, parsing

I have a website in Flask, which is basically a Twitter clone, where I have a `textarea` element for recording tweets, and I'm using MySQL to post the tweet to the database.

Now the problem is, when someone tweets something that contains symbols, the `flask-mysql connector` can't convert the symbols into text and it breaks the program. For example, when I tweet:

```
# When I tweet this
The '%^&!@#:';.,}{][ characters break everything
```

using the following code in `main.py`:

```
# This code handles the tweet
conn = mysql.connect()
cursor = conn.cursor()

try: 
    cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO tweets (username, tweet_content) values ('%s', %s)", (session['username'], content))
    conn.commit()
    success = True
except Exception as e:
    print("!!!!   error : ", e)
finally: 
    conn.close()
```

the `error` reads:

```
!!!!   error :  (1064, "You have an error in your 
SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'mohit2004'', 'The\\r\\n!@$@#%@%&amp;^*%^!#%@!^%' at line 1")
```

I know this is happening because the symbols can't be converted into text strings, and when the tweet_text is passed, the ' symbols mix and break the code.

Is there a way to convert all these symbols to something that can be stored into the database like `'` to `&single_quote`, `"` to `&double_quote`

Something like that, and then convert it back to normal text, when a user views it.

I can't find any relevant search term for a service like this on the internet, and I know that this question will be highly devoted, but if you know any service like, or if they are built into Flask, then let me know.

Edit highlight: the `html.escape` function does not work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in module `html` with its functions:

- `escape` to convert characters to HTML entities.
- `unescape` to convert HTML entities to characters.

Here is your example:

```
>>> import html
>>>
>>> text = "The ' character breaks everything"
>>> html_text = html.escape(text)
>>> html_text
The &#x27; character breaks everything
>>>
>>> html.unescape(html_text)
The ' character breaks everything
```

Comment: Thanks! Was searching for this.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Hey @Anwarvic , I tested but it is not relevant in my case. I've edited the question accordingly